# android listactivity

Tags: android-intent, listactivity, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to create "ListActivity" but I unable to see the output as list. I used the people code. Moreover, I didn't got any error in below code. Please help regarding this issue.

`package com.wordpress.sree7k7;`

`import android.app.ListActivity;`
`import android.content.Intent;`
`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.view.View;`
`import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;`
`import android.widget.ListView;`

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

```
String classes[]={ "MainActivity", "example1","example2",
        "example3","example4","example5","example6"};
@Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1));
}@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try {
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.wordpress.sree7k7.Menu"+ cheese);
    Intent ourIntent= new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try to change bgcolor of ourClass so you can figure out whether your listview doesn't show up or it already starts new(ourClass) activity